# Loading dynamic url in div element using html/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having some trouble loading a custom URL. The basic idea is that a user will click on a series of navigation links which will then dynamically load the appropriate content in a tabbed bootstrap jumbotron. The series of navigation links varies based on information stored in the backend (it is accessed via a for-loop in the html template using django's templating language).

The problem I'm having is that I have to make the function call as each element is accessed in the for loop and create a url to be loaded based on the primary key of the content. I tried to emulate this very basic example for onclick events: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

The url that is attempted to load doesn't evaluate my function in activate.js, loading selectCourseURL(var) instead of the value of the function. Second, I think that there is something that I am not handling right with the type of element I am using. Removing the href attribute (a href="#{{course.pk}}" ) here accomplishes nothing as does changing the loading id from #best_price to match to "#{{course.pk}}". I want the content to load when anyone clicks on the text to be loaded, by default, into the best_price tab (which is the default active tab). Any info on where I may be going wrong here is greatly appreciated!

Here is my code:

get_my_book.html

```
{% extends 'accounts/profile.html' %}
{% block aaa %}
      {% for course in userprofile.courses.all%}
            <p class="minicoursenav"><a href="#{{course.pk}}" 
onclick=  ("#best_price" ).load("selectCourseURL('{{course.pk}}')")>
&nbsp;&nbsp;{{course.department_abbr}} {{ course.course_num }}</a>
            </p>
      {% endfor %}

<div class="container">        
    <div class="jumbotron">

  <div id="content">
<ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#best_price" data-toggle="tab">Best Price</a></li>
    <li><a href="#very_good" data-toggle="tab">Very Good</a></li>
    <li><a href="#good" data-toggle="tab">Good</a></li>
    <li><a href="#fine" data-toggle="tab">Fine</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="best_price">
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="very_good">
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="good">
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="fine">
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div> 
{% endblock %}
```

activate.js

```
function selectCourseURL(p_key){
    var url = "/books/select_my_book/best_price/";
    return (url + p_key+ "/"); 
}
```

(**note**: accounts/profile.html is the parent template, which correctly calls activate.js at the end of the file. I have confirmed that this url is reading this by putting a series of commands into activate.js which were successfully executed. The calls to the backend as in {{ course.attribute }} are valid for this particular url. Jquery has been included correctly in the parent template. The load function can be called successfully in activate.js file)

Comment: You hav syntax errors in onclick attribute: it has to be quoted and '#best_price' jQuery selector needs to be wrapped in $, or jQuery like this: onclick=  '$("#best_price").load("selectCourseURL({{course.pk}})")'

Answer (score 0):

jQuery 'load' function consider 'selectCourseURL(var)' is a url name, not a function call.

I'd suggest to implement the code like this:

```
{% for course in serprofile.courses.all %}
    <p class="minicoursenav">
      <a class='course_link' data='{{ course.pk }}' href='#'>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;{{ course.department_abbr}} {{ course.course_num }}
      </a>
    </p>
{% endfor %}
```

activate.js:

```
$('.course_link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var course_pk = $(this).attr('data');
    var url = selectCourseUrl(course_pk);
    $("#best_price").load(url);
    return false;
})
```